# Centos: vsftpd 2.2.2 - 500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_cmd

Tags: linux, command-line, centos, ftp, vsftpd

I'm very new to Linux, and I'm currently experimenting with it and several services in order to familiarize myself to it. I've installed vsftpd to access the machine over ftp however I'm getting the error below:

```
>>>  USER username
<<<  331 Please specify the password.

>>>  PASS ***********
<<<  500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/home/username

  --> FTP reconnected
>>>  PWD
<<<  500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_cmd
Error EElFTPSUnacceptedReplyError: Unaccepted server reply (error code is 500)
```

I've confirmed port 21 is open. The versions being used are vsftpd v. 2.2.2 on centos 6.8.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

J

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/174235/280048

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks for your reply. I've ensured that the user 'username' and the group he belongs to has full access (CHMOD 777), however I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved this by disabling SELinux, which from what I can understand is similar  to what UAC is to windows.

This was achieved by checking the status and determined that it was in enforcing mode:

```
sestatus
```

Once that was determined, I changed this to permissive through the following command:

```
setenforce 0
```

Restarted vsftpd service using `service vsftpd restart` and was able to access the machine over ftp.